# How to do localization in Google Closure

Tags: localization, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library, google-closure-templates

Currently I am using just plain text in my Closure application. I want to add localizations to those text. I just found several articles about goog.getMsg function which is used to do this kind of localization. As far as I understood it is done in compile time. How can we change language in run-time when user clicks a button? What is the easiest way to do this using Closure?

Comment: i8nl is compile time in closure.

Answer (score 3):

I have actually achieved a runtime i18n. I use .soy templates with `{msg}` tags in them. When you compile .soy to .js, these calls get compiled to goog.getMsg calls. What I had to do was:

1. Find all `.js` files that had `goog.getMsg(` in them
2. Prepend `goog.require("myApp.i18n");\n`
3. Replace all `goog.getMsg(` calls with `myApp.i18n.translate(`
4. Replace all `MSG_*` property names with `myprefix_MSG_*`

Why all this: One cannot override goog.getMsg directly, because it is considered a compiler primitive and does not allow any manipulation whatsoever. Same applies for `MSG_*` properties.

`myApp.i18n.translate` is a function that accepts string, tries to look it up in a locale map (which is passed in runtime) and returns `goog.getMsg` result using the localized string (`goog.getMsg` does some handy placeholder replacements).

While this is not a very pretty solution, it works and allows me to change language in runtime, using only one compiled file for all languages.

The actual code includes a few hacks that allows me to use the generated description and use JSON files instead of the strange-looking closure file format, but the gist is the same.

### However!

**What you really should do is to compile several files from your app and load different .js file for every language.**

I had to use this solution, because I need to support hundreds of different configurations and several languages: it would be insane to compile thousands of .js files, when one compilation takes 30+ seconds.

Comment: automated build yo! as for your solution, it is interesting, I would actually recommend writing it as a compiler plugin. If you would like some help with that, I would gladly assist.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not a single click language switch solution, I find it very comfortable as it allows to use same source of localized texts for both Soy templates and `goog.getMsg()` in JS code. It is sort of undocumented way of using Googles own XML format of translations called XTB.

You will end up with different compiled .js file for each language, so to switch locale you have to reload different JS file.

Apart from standard Closure tools there is 3rd party tool called XtbGenerator, which can be found here: https://github.com/kuzmisin/xtbgenerator.

---

Now the workflow:

1. Compile your templates using `SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar` with `--shouldGenerateGoogMsgDefs --bidiGlobalDir 1` options. No locale yet.
2. Create dependecies file using `calcdeps.py`
3. Run `closurebuilder.py` with `--compiler_jar` set to `XtbGenerator.jar` file and with `--compiler_flags="--xtb_output_file=origin.xtb"` parameter.

   This will create a file called `origin.xtb`, which you can then use as a base for your translations. It will contain all texts both from Soy templates (in `{msg}` blocks) and your JS files (where `var MSG_TEST = goog.getMsg('Text');` is used).
4. Copy `origin.xtb` to for example `translated.cs_CZ.xtb`, change the `lang` attribute in the file and translate all the texts there.
5. Compile the app for given locale the standard way using `closurebuilder.py` and `compiler.jar`. Use parameters:

   `--compiler_flags="--translations_file=translated.cs_CZ.xtb"`

   `--compiler_flags="--define=goog.LOCALE='cs_CZ'"`

   This will create you compiled version for single locale.

Nice examples of all these steps are here: http://www.closurecheatsheet.com/skeleton

It is unfortunate that there is almost no official documentation for this.

---

**XTB format**:

The format is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE translationbundle>
<translationbundle lang="cs">
    <translation id="4127240967364168948" key="MSG_6LRZ706911HM" source="..\test.soy.js" desc="description">test</translation>
</translationbundle>
```

`id` and for soy templates also `key` attribute is autogenerated by compiler/extractor

This is most probably some Google internal format with tools for this not yet open-sourced.

---

**Note about XtbGenerator**:

It internally uses the Closure Compiler code to go through your JS codes and extract the messages. The dowloadable version however is built with older version of Closure Compiler, so it was throwing some errors for me.

I did a quick and dirty hack by copying `goog` directories from current version of `compiler.jar` to `XtbGenerator.jar`.