# Are there reasons to use XMB and XTB message formats over XLF or XLIFF in Angular's i18n?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I have not been able to tell if XMB/XTB and XLF/XLIFF are just different flavors with the same capabilities, or if there are good reasons to use one vs the other when doing translations using Angular's i18n. Is one format more dominant in translation software? Are there things about XMB/XTB that are better for Angular?

The Angular i18n documentation lists them all as options, and seems to default to XLF, but doesn't seem to explain much about any differences or advantages or disadvantages of the file formats.

Comment: Did you ever find out? :)

Comment: @LeonardoChaia nope :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to do localization in Google Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645568/how-to-do-localization-in-google-closure) XTB is Google's internal i18n format, that they use with Closure Compiler. I guess the reason it's in Angular is to support Google's internal apps and toolchain.